# Understanding the behaviour of divs and

Tags: html, css, floating

I am new to HTML and CSS and to Stack Overflow community and for one of my assignment, I need to evenly place multiple `<div>`s next to each other in a container `<div>`. I used `float:left` for each of the inner `<div>`s. But when I do that, the outer (container) div collapses all the way up to the top. What I've come to understand is that the floating elements are moved out of the normal flow of the content and any element after them are placed in the normal flow.
I need to understand the working style of floating elements as well as `display:inline-block`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
A sample markup in its simplest form looks like this:

```
<style>
 #xouter{
    width:80%;
    margin-left:9%;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#xleftcol{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    background:#809900;
}
 #xmiddlecol{
    float: left;
    width: 34%;
    background:#eff2df;
}
#xrightcol{
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    background:#d2da9c;
}
</style>
    <body>
       <div id="xouter">
          <div id="xleftcol">
          This is the left col : This is the left col :This is the left col :This is the left col :This is the left col :This is the left col :This is the left col :This is the left col :This is the left col :This is the left col :This is the left col 
          </div>
          <div id="xmiddlecol">
          This is the middlecol: This is the middlecol: This is the middlecol: This is the middlecol: This is the middlecol: This is the middlecol: This is the middlecol: This is the middlecol: This is the middlecol: This is the middlecol: This is the middlecol: This is the middlecol: 
          </div>
          <div id="xrightcol">
              This is the rightcol : This is the rightcol : This is the rightcol : This is the rightcol : This is the rightcol : This is the rightcol : This is the rightcol ::
          </div>
        </div>

    </body>
```

[This is a screen shot of what I have:
1- 3 divs with no floating or display property set
2- the same divs but with float-left property
3- lastly, with display:inline-block property (no floating property)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD2lN.jpg)

Comment: a `.` in css refers to a `class` and a `#` refers to an `id`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRLmRV

Comment: Is that a question? What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use either `float:left/right` OR `display:inline-block`, not both.

Change the three `float:left` lines in your CSS to `display:inline-block` and it should give you the result you want.

Edit: Michael Coker correctly noted that you are mismatching the IDs in your HTML with `.classname` in your CSS.

Comment: Thanks smekosh for answering, even though I messed my code. Your suggestion did work and brought me a step closer. Now the inner divs fit nicely inside the outer div. The only problem is that their bottom border line up with the div as opposed to their top border.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, the periods need to be replaced with pound signs. A period refers to a class. A pound sign refers to an ID. Your markup uses IDs but you're referencing them as classes in your CSS..

Comment: my apologies... a novice mistake :(